# Compute $m+n$, given $4n^2+9m^2-240n-720m+18000=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$4n^2+9m^2-240n-720m+18000=0$

$m+n=?$

a)$70$

b)$60$

c)$40$

d)$30$

The answer is a) $70$. But I have no idea how you can get to this answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because we have
$$9(m-40)^2+4(n-30)^2=0.$$

Comment: And of course, we are dealing with real numbers here. So this equation is only true for `m = 40` and `n = 30`, giving `m + n = 70`.

Answer (score 1):

This equals to $4(n-30)^2+9(m-40)^2=0$.